# Python social auth partial pipeline resume after form submit button

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I have a partial func pipeline that waits for a form to click the **submit** button.
When the button is clicked, the pipeline should move on. 
I was thinking on this approach, but how can I get the request object in pipeline?

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit", name="SumbitSocialData">


@partial
def partial_pipeline(backend, user, response, is_new=None, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    request = ?
    if 'SumbitSocialData' in request.POST:
        # move on
```

How can i acces the request object in pipeline?

Does someone has a better ideea about how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, by adding a `submit_social_data` value in the session, inside the view code:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    ...
    self.request.session['submit_social_data'] = True
    return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Than, in the pipeline I check if is a new social account and if it clicked the button:

```
@partial
def twitter_email(backend, user, response, is_new=None,  *args, **kwargs):
     ...
     submit_social_data = backend.strategy.session.get('submit_social_data', None)
     if is_new and not submit_social_data:
                return redirect('redirect_url')
```

Comment: Hey, I am stuck in exactly same situation. Can you please elaborate on your solution?

Comment: Hi, I added a new line in form_valid and correct my answer, submit_social_data = .. .
I set submit_social_data flag as True in session, if the form is validated, than I get it  back in the pipeline. If the button is clicked and form is validated, the pipeline will move on, because that flag is set to True.